# Updatepanel gives full postback instead of asyncpostback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, postback

I have run into what seems to be a very famous problem: My updatepanel fires a full postback instead of a async postback. The normal solution is to give all controls you add dynamically an ID, which I have done, but I still get a full postback instead of my async postback...

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ItemsUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
   <Triggers>
   </Triggers>    
   <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:ListView ID="PlayerItems" runat="server" GroupItemCount="5" 
                                    onitemdatabound="PlayerItems_ItemDataBound">
   <LayoutTemplate>

   ... Listview stuff ...

    </asp:ListView> 

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The interesting part is the C# code behind (method PlayerItems_ItemDataBound), which is like the following:

```
            ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
            imgBtn.ID = "itemBtn";
            imgBtn.Width = Unit.Pixel(30);
            imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Game/Items/" + myItem.ItemImageUrl;

            ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
            menu.BoundControls.Add(imgBtn);
            menu.ItemCommand += new CommandEventHandler(menu_ItemCommand);

            menu.AutoHide = true;
            menu.RolloverColor = Color.Gray;
            menu.ID = "MenuMenu";

            Panel panel = (Panel)(e.Item.FindControl("ItemPanel"));
            panel.Controls.Add(imgBtn);
            panel.Controls.Add(menu);

            AsyncPostBackTrigger trig = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
            trig.ControlID = menu.UniqueID;
            trig.EventName = "ItemCommand";
            ItemsUpdatePanel.Triggers.Add(trig);
```

So, I actually add an AsyncPostBackTrigger to the menu, so the ItemCommand event should be registered. What happends when I click an item in this contextmenu, is a full postback happends.

I have been trying to play with the ChildrenAsTriggers property without help. I have also been moving the AsyncPostBackTrigger code up and down, also without help.

Thanks a lot beforehand..!
Lars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) documentation:

> **Programmatically adding
>   AsyncPostBackTrigger controls is not
>   supported.** To programmatically
>   register a postback control, use the
>   [RegisterAsyncPostBackControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) method of
>   the [ScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) control. Then call
>   the [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx) method of the [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx)
>   control when the control posts back.

Comment: Urh.. Not what I had hoped.. But that's how it's done!

Thanks a lot! I'm really grateful! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, kicking myself!

UpdatePanel1.Update();

Answer (score 31):

I had the same experience when populating a CheckBoxList inside a ListView inside a Panel in an UpdatePanel. It was solved by adding this code in the CheckBoxList:

```
ClientIDMode="AutoID"
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you so much.  MS changed how ClientID's are generated in .net 4.0 from "AutoID" to "Predictable" and I guess the ScriptManager or UpdatePanel's weren't updated correctly to use it.  I can't find documentation on why that is anywhere or if it was left that way by design.

Comment: I hate that this is the solution, but it works! Thanks!

Comment: I already had AutoID on globally, but I simply needed to add IDs to my linkbuttons in my listview. No triggers were needed.

Comment: Even with ClientID set to Static globally, setting my RadioButtonLists and CheckBoxLists to AutoID was still the solution.