# Accordion's First Pane Flashes On Partial Postback

Tags: asp.net, postback, accordion

I'm using an ASP.NET Accordion control with lots of panes for a data entry form.  Within several of the panes are some UpdatePanels, so that some controls within those panels can be enabled or disabled to prevent users from entering values into fields which are precluded by values they've entered elsewhere.

It all works fine, but for some reason, on about half of the occasions where an UpdatePanel postback is triggered (by a specified AsyncPostBack Trigger), the first pane of the Accordion momentarily expands and collapses.  This gives that horrible 'flashing' experience you get when a page does a full postback, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid by using UpdatePanels.

The problem doesn't seem to relate to the contents of the first pane - I tried completely deleting the first pane, so that the second pane became the first, and the same thing happens.

Anybody got any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

UPDATED WITH CODE
This is an example of one of the panels. Don't be too offended by the use of a table - it's an actual table, I'm not just using it for layout purposes!

```
<tr class="grouprow">
    <td>Transportation</td>
    <td><asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblTransportation" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("AdmissionTransportation")%>' AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblTransportation_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Unknown" Value="" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="True" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="False" />                                    
    </asp:RadioButtonList></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="grouprow">
    <td>Transportation Duration</td>
    <td><asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTransportationHours" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rblTransportation" EventName="selectedindexchanged" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTransportationHours" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AdmissionTransportationHours")%>' CssClass="tinytextbox" />
                <label class="unit">Hours</label>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revTransportationHours" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTransportationHours" ValidationExpression="\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?"
                    ValidationGroup="Past30Days" ErrorMessage="Invalid format for Transporation Duration. Please enter in format 'xxx.xx', e.g. '3.25'" Display="Dynamic" 
                    CssClass="error" >*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID="rvTransportationDuration" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTransportationHours" CssClass="error" ValidationGroup="Past30Days" type="Double"
                    ErrorMessage="The Transportation Duration cannot be more than 100" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="100" >*</asp:RangeValidator>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have an `UpdatePanel` wrapping your entire accordion, or are the `UpdatePanel`s exclusively inside the accordion panels?

Comment: Exclusively inside.  There is no panel wrapping the whole accordion.

Comment: Are you sure a full postback isn't slipping through? It just seems like the flash is due to the page reloading and the accordion being re-rendered by jQuery.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I can't detect any flashing of controls outside the accordion.

Comment: I've added `If ScriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack = True Then
            lblPostback.Text = "Async Postback"
        Else
            lblPostback.Text = "Full Postback"
        End If` To my Page Load event.  If I've done that correctly then the indication is that I am getting a full postback each time.  But if so, I don't know why...

Comment: Can you post your UpdatePanel code? You might have an issue with your `UpdateMode` and `ChildrenAsTriggers` attributes, or your `<Triggers>` section.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is gloriously simple, though I'm too tired to figure out why it works just now.  I simply need to set `ClientIDMode = AutoID` on the RadioButtonLists and CheckBoxLists and they now trigger an asynchronous postback rather than a full one.  They don't need to be within their own UpdatePanels either.

I got the answer [from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319156/updatepanel-gives-full-postback-instead-of-asyncpostback/4484867#comment-7093883).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need your `rblTransportation` `RadioButtonList`  wrapped in an UpdatePanel as well.

Since that control isn't in an UpdatePanel, it causes a full postback.

Comment: I was so convinced that this was the right answer, that I almost marked it as such before even trying it, cursing myself for my stupidity.  But to my surprise, even wrapping the RadioButtonList in its own UpdatePanel doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try `<asp:blablacontrol  style="Display:none;"> </asp:control>`
modalpanels has same problem and this codes solved my problem

Comment: Are you suggesting that I add that style to the Accordion itself? Or to the pane that is flashing?  Or do you mean me to add a whole new control just for this purpose?

I had the same problem with ModalPopup Panels too, and solved it the same way, but they're different - you don't want them to be visible most of the time.  The Accordion I do want visible!